# Changeset function for association

Tags: elixir, ecto

I have following schema:

```
schema "countries" do

    belongs_to :code, CountryCode, references: :alpha2
    belongs_to :language, LanguageCode, references: :code
    field :text, :string

    timestamps
end
```

My question is, how to write a changeset function for the schema above?

I tried:

```
  def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do

      model
      |> cast(params, [:text])
      |> cast_assoc(:code)
      |> cast_assoc(:language)
      |> validate_required([:code, :language, :text])

  end
```

And I've got error message:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{text: "Switzerland"},
 errors: [language: {"is invalid", [type: :map]},
  code: {"is invalid", [type: :map]}], data: #Busiket.Country<>, valid?: false>
```

**UPDATE**

I rewrite the changeset function:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do

      model
      |> cast(params, [:code_id, :language_id, :text])
      |> cast_assoc(:code)
      |> cast_assoc(:language)
      |> validate_required([:code, :language, :text])
end
```

and I've got:

```
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil, changes: %{text: "Switzerland"},
 errors: [language: {"is invalid", [type: :map]},
  code: {"is invalid", [type: :map]}], data: #Busiket.Country<>, valid?: false>
```

Sorry about it, here is the schema from my `LanguageCode`:

```
schema "languages_code" do

    has_one :code, Country, foreign_key: :lang
    field :text, :string

    timestamps
end
```

**UPDATE**

I test it again in the shell:

```
iex(4)> v = %{code: %{code: "CH"}, language: %{alpha2: "DE"}, text: "Schweiz"}
%{code: %{code: "CH"}, language: %{alpha2: "DE"}, text: "Schweiz"}
iex(5)> c = Country.changeset(%Country{}, v)                                  
#Ecto.Changeset<action: nil,
 changes: %{code: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{},
    errors: [alpha2: {"can't be blank", []}, alpha3: {"can't be blank", []}],
    data: #Busiket.CountryCode<>, valid?: false>,
   language: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, changes: %{},
    errors: [code: {"can't be blank", []}, text: {"can't be blank", []}],
    data: #Busiket.LanguageCode<>, valid?: false>, text: "Schweiz"}, errors: [],
 data: #Busiket.Country<>, valid?: false>
```

I've forgot to mention, that the data on the language_code table is already available:

[image]

Comment: Since you didn't post the rest of the schemas, it's hard to tell.  Your "Language" data might be invalid.  It works for simple cases: https://gist.github.com/stavro/9d1dcaa3c68a71880aece951005c4d97

Comment: I insert the languagecode schema on post.

Comment: I updated my post again.

Answer (score 0):

The changeset being produced is trying to insert 3 new records, Country, LanguageCode and CountryCode.

There is insufficient data in your params to insert all these records:

```
%{code: %{code: "CH"}, language: %{alpha2: "DE"}, text: "Schweiz"}
```

It can't insert into the CountryCode table without the `alpha2` and `alpha3` fields:

```
code: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, 
                      changes: %{},
                      errors: [alpha2: {"can't be blank", []}, alpha3: {"can't be blank", []}],
                      data: #Busiket.CountryCode<>, 
                      valid?: false>`
```

It can't insert into the LanguageCode table without the `code` and `text` fields:

```
language: #Ecto.Changeset<action: :insert, 
                          changes: %{},
                          errors: [code: {"can't be blank", []}, text: {"can't be blank", []}],
                          data: #Busiket.LanguageCode<>,  
                          valid?: false>
```

If you aren't intending to insert into all these tables, then you'll need to populate the `language_id` and `code_id` params.

```
params = %{language_id: "DE", code_id: "CH", text: "Schweiz"}
```

then remove the `cast_assoc` calls from the changeset function:

```
def changeset(model, params \\ %{}) do
  model
  |> cast(params, [:code_id, :language_id, :text])
  |> validate_required([:code_id, :language_id, :text])
end
```

Alternatively, you can preload the associations and use `put_assoc`:

```
def changeset(
      model = %Country{}, 
      country_code = %CountryCode{}, 
      language_code = %LanguageCode{}, 
      params \\ %{}) do

  model
  |> cast(params, [:text])
  |> put_assoc(:code, country_code)
  |> put_assoc(:language, language_code)
  |> validate_required([:text, :code, :language])
end
```

The [docs](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Changeset.html#cast_assoc/3) for `cast_assoc` has some additional explanation of the differences between `cast_assoc` and `put_assoc`:

> In other words, cast_assoc/3 is useful when the associated data is managed alongside the parent struct, all at once. If each side of the association is managed separately, it is preferable to use put_assoc/3 and directly instruct Ecto how the association should look like.